# Change size of text

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I have such part html template. I use bootstrap for stylish.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 positon-relative-block-down">
     <p class="down">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 positon-relative-block-up">
      <p class="up">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-8 col-xs-11 positon-relative-block-describe">
       <p class="describe">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

I have such problem: if my window size will be col-xs, my text does not fit. My question is how add style for text for col-xs, which must be smaller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One example could be:

```
@media screen and (max-width:480px)
{
  [class*='col-xs'] p
  {
    font-size:10px;
  }
}
```

In this way, you force `font-size` for all elements containing a paragraph `p` inside a generic "*col-xs*" class (`col-xs-6`, `col-xs-3`) specifically an only when screen width is lower than typical screen width used by XS suffix of Bootstrap classes.

Comment: Is possible... for example if there is a `font-size` already defined for `p` tags. in this case, it is enough to modify selector in order to specifically target this kind of elements.

Comment: Thank you, i try your answer )

Answer (score 1):

I recomend you to try use vw instead of px for font size, example:

```
div { font-size:2vw}
```

The vw is ViewportWidth that will make your font responsive to the device width, try it is very usefull for responsives designs, you could see a example here:
https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/
Thats was the solution for me in responsive world.
Hope its help you.

Comment: do my text very small.

Comment: try more, use 4vw, 10vw, or 1 vw or 0.5 0.2vw 
VW means Viewport Width so is referer to the width of the screen you could also use vh if you developer refering to height but is heavy, i recomend vw.